# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0+} \left[ \sin(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin(x)}\right] $?

Tags: calculus, limits

For $x>0$, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left[ \sin(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin(x)}\right]
$$These are two forms of $0^\infty$ and $\infty^0$. I know these are to be evaluated separately and then added. But how do I start?

Comment: Is your question solved in a satisfying way? If no tell us what's wrong, if yes, could you be so kind to accept an answer? :)

Comment: Sorry, for being late to respond... @Dominic: Yes, I am satisfied. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first start with 
$$a^b=e^{b\cdot \ln(a)}$$ 
(this is the definition of $a^b$ for $a>0$).
and because of the $e$ function is continuous 
$$\lim e^{x_n}=e^{\lim x_n}$$
This is because of the sequence definition or test for continuous functions, a function $f$ is continuous if for every convergent sequence $x_n$ 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n)$$
Since both term are greater equal we can check the first, and afterwards the second. 
$$\sin(x)^\frac{1}{x}=e^{\ln(\sin(x))\cdot \frac{1}{x}}$$
Because of it is continuous we check
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}$$
As we have a $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$ expression here, we can use L'hospital 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 } \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{x}=-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=-\infty$$ (the $-$ must be there because $\ln(\sin(x))<0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$
And because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow - \infty} e^{x}=0$$ the first term vanishes.

The second Term is handled like this:
$$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin(x)} = e^{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sin(x)}$$

Now 
$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cdot \sin(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}$$
with L'hospital 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}=
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{\cos(x)}=0 $$
so the second term is $e^0$ so the limit is 1.

Comment: could you link to a proof of that, didn't know that before.

Comment: of which exactly ?

Comment: That because $e$ is a continuous function that $\lim e^{x_n}=e^{\lim x_n}$ I didn't know that if $f\left(h\left(x\right)\right)$ is continuous then $\lim f\left(h\left(x\right)\right)$ = $f\left(\lim h\left(x\right)\right)$

Comment: ok i added the stuff, as i learned it in university this was the definition of continuous, which one is yours, so i can link the right proof ?

Comment: I am not at university yet.

Comment: ok than what a continuous function is for you? I need a point to start for the proof ^^

Comment: Just know that all the points "touch", thats what is need for the  ap calculus test, so that is all I am taught.  At least, now I a term to look up the proof on the internet, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $0^{\infty}$ is not an indeterminate form. Then
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \left[ \sin(x)^{\frac{1}{x}}+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin(x)}\right]=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin(x)}=\lim_{y \rightarrow +\infty}y^{\sin(1/y)}=\lim_{y \rightarrow +\infty}(y^{1/y})^{y\sin(1/y)}=1$$
The other limit to $0^-$is complex infinity.

Comment: is $0^\infty$ really not an indeterminate form? I mean $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0^n $ is obviously 0

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: I didn't learn at school that this is an indeterminate case. Or is it? Things should be clear (btw).

Comment: It's indeterminate, $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{{-x^{-2}}^\frac{1}{x}}$$ should be $0$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: can you show me this in any calculus book?

Comment: Are you serious? I gave you a counterexample for $0^\infty$ is determinate, in the limit above it is $1$ in my example it is $0$, shall i prove that the limit of my example is $0$ ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: oh i am sry i misread $0^\infty$ isn't indeterminate since every geometric sequence $q^n$ with $|q|<1$ converges to 0

Comment: @ Dominic Michaelis: If it's correct, then you have the possibility to upvote my answer. :-)